# Inserting numbers or polynomials into a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Essentially my issue is that, in the algorithm im working on, I construct a polynomial by taking factors out of a list and multiplying them. For example, i have

```
f=(1 + t + 3 t^2 + t^3) (6 + 3 t + 2 t^2 + t^4)
```

How can I now replace t with say, a number or another polynomial? And how can I do this for any polynomial f?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One standard way to do this is to define your polynomial in the first place as a function:

```
f[t_] := (1 + t + 3 t^2 + t^3) (6 + 3 t + 2 t^2 + t^4)
```

Now you can evaluate this at any number using f[3] and with any other argument:

```
f[x^2 + 2]
```

Then apply Expand or Simplify if desired.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear[f, t, x]

f = (1 + t + 3 t^2 + t^3) (6 + 3 t + 2 t^2 + t^4);
```

You can replace `t` with a number using `ReplaceAll`:

```
f /. t :> 3
```

> 6612

Or replace it with another polynomial and (optionally) expand it:

```
f /. t :> (x^2 + 1) // Expand
```

> 72 + 186 x^2 + 230 x^4 + 182 x^6 + 105 x^8 + 42 x^10 + 10 x^12 + x^14

Or replace with another polynomial and then with a number:

```
f /. t :> (x^2 + 1) /. x :> 3
```

> 13419396